# How to run a service without being depending on activity going to background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm building an application that must does the following

1. when the user opens the application, the application starts (*in the background*) searching for some places using GPS and WiFi. and gives the user a notification when finding a location.
2. The searching process **must** start working in the background when the MainActivity launches, not when the MainActivity become in background
3. and mustn't stop if I finished the MainActivity,
4. it shouldn't stop also if the user opened another application.
5. It may only be stopped when the application is closed.

I searched for a way to make these four steps and I found that I can use services to run my code in background, but the problem with services is that it's bounded with activities; if activity is destroyed then the service would stop working [[xamarin documentation]](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/).

How can I achieve those five conditions?